# What is the name of this operator "^"?

Tags: c++

I know that this operator does the "AND logical operator" but I don't know how to deal with it and if it deals with decimal numbers or just binary numbers ?

Comment: This is not a C++/CLI question, so slightly out-of-topic, but for the record, `^` is also the managed reference unary operator in C++/CLI. If you have `String ^ myString ;`, myString is a managed reference to a .NET String object (in the same way in `int * myInt ;` myInt is a pointer to an int).

Comment: *I know that this operator does the "AND logical operator"* You should revisit your *knowledge* as that is not a logical or. Logical or in C++ are either `and` or `&&`.

Answer (score 9):

It is the the [`XOR` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/):

> **XOR (Exclusive Or)**
>
> This operation is performed between two bits (a and b). The result is
> 1 if either one of the two bits is 1, but not in the case that both
> are. There for, if neither or both of them are equal to 1 the result
> is 0.

Answer (score 4):

That is the bitwise XOR operator.

It performs an [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation) operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the logical AND, it's the bitwise XOR. It operates on *integers*, which are always binary numbers in C++, and may be overloaded for other types.

Comment: The `^` operator also operates on type `bool`, so it is both a bitwise and a logical XOR operation.

Answer (score 0):

That's the bitwise `XOR` operator (so not logical, not AND) and decimal numbers are represented as binaries, so of course it works for them as well.

The logical AND is `&&` and the bitwise AND is `&`.

Comment: It would probably be more correct to say that C++ doesn't support decimal numbers (except that theoretically, floating point could be base 10---but I've never heard of an implementation where this was the case).  There are external libraries that do support decimal numbers.  (But I rather suspect that that's not what the OP had in mind, and that your answer addresses his issues.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: What do you mean when you said *" C++ doesn't support decimal numbers"*? What do you mean by *"decimal numbers"* in this context?

Comment: @Nawaz C++ has no support for decimal numbers.  The io libraries have support for converting external representations in various bases, but internally, integral types are required by the standard to be binary, and the floating point formats I've seen have all had bases of powers of 2 (2, 8 or 16).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for your response, but I didn't get what you meant by "decimal numbers"?

Comment: @Nawaz A decimal number is a number represented in base 10.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't get it. If I write `double d = 49878.94`. Isn't `d` here a decimal number? And then say `decimal d = 49878.94`. What is the difference?

Comment: @Nawaz On a PC, `d` will be IEEE, which is binary; on an IBM mainframe, it will be base 16.  I'm not aware of a platform which supports (or supported) C++, or even C, where it would be decimal.  Input and output converts, with a possible loss of precision.  (`49878.94` is not exactly representable in an IEEE double.  Try outputting `d` with 17 digits precision.)

Comment: @Nawaz WRT `decimal`, there isn't a decimal data type in C++.  This would have to be a third party class.  There have been proposals for a build-in decimal type, but they aren't (yet) part of the language.  And under the proposals, if you later tried to compare your second `d` with the first, they would not compare equal.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Of course the datatype `decimal` is hypothetical (which I thought is obvious)